# how to implements a java SAM interface in Kotlin?

Tags: android, functional-programming, kotlin, functional-interface

In Java it is possible to write code like this:

```
model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, new Observer<ProductEntity>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable ProductEntity productEntity) {
        model.setProduct(productEntity);
    }
});
```

However trying to override local function in Kotlin results in:
[image]

---

**Question:** is it possible to override local function in Kotlin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using object expression instead.

```
//       the parentheses must be removed if Observer is an interface  ---V
model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, object:Observer<ProductEntity>(){
   override fun onChanged(productEntity:ProductEntity?) {
      model.setProduct(productEntity);
   }
});
```

**IF** the `Observer` is a java **SAM** interface (*kotlin **SAM** interfaces aren't currently supported*) then you can using lambda expression instead as further:

```
model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, Observer<ProductEntity>{
      model.setProduct(it);
});
```

**OR** using a lambda expression instead, for example:

```
// specify the lambda parameter type ---v
model.getObservableProduct().observe<ProductEntity>(this) {
      model.setProduct(it);
};
```

Comment: Perfect answer, both methods works. And, yes, Observer is a SAM interface.